# What are all these versions in conda package listing?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

When I run the following command:

```
conda search python
```

I got the following output as a result:

```
(...)
python                         3.8.5 cpython_h85f3143_0  conda-forge
python                         3.8.5 cpython_hc2483ac_0  conda-forge
python                         3.8.5 cpython_hfe7aed7_0  conda-forge
python                         3.8.5 h85f3143_1_cpython  conda-forge
python                         3.8.5 hc2483ac_1_cpython  conda-forge
python                         3.8.5 hfe7aed7_1_cpython  conda-forge
(...)
```

What are all these versions, since I cannot find any explanation [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python).

Comment: Are you referring to `cpython_h85f3143_0`? These are [build string](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#build-number-and-string) plus build number. As a user you can almost always treat them as conda-forge internals. You would install python 3.8.5 usually by `conda install python=3.8` or rarely `conda install python=3.8.5`.  In principle you could do `conda install "python=3.8.5=*cpython"` to install a version with a build string that ends with `cpython` but I don't think users would ever want to do this. Is your question what they mean exactly?

Comment: Actually, [switching the blas implementation](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html?highlight=blas#switching-blas-implementation) is one of the very rare use-cases where conda-forge users would actually directly make use of the build-string.

Comment: @cel, yes, that answers my question. Thanks! Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.